# Sending notification to custom teams application

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am working on a custom app that will load data in the personal tab from an external system. Everything works fine when I am on the app.

If the user is on the Calls or Chat tab and the external system is having something new for the user we want to notify the user in the chat or activity feed so that the user can revisit the custom app and review the data.

Please suggest how to achieve it.

Thanks,
Pratap

Comment: One way is to send an activity feed notification to a user using application permissions like below: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-sendactivitynotification?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications, https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed

Comment: Issue is resolved using sendActivityNotification API